# How do I make a rule fail without proving that something is false?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make an `invert/2`. I want it to ignore the order of its arguments, so that you don't need to worry about which half of the inversion is the one you know, and so that you don't have to repeat yourself when stating inversions as facts. I currently have

```
invert(Left, Right) :-
    call_with_depth_limit(invert(Right, Left), 1, Result),
    Result \= depth_limit_exceeded.
```

as the first `invert` rule. This mostly works, but if `invert(a, b).`, then `?- invert(b, X).` gives both `X = a` and `false`, which is not what I want at all.

Comment: Doesn't `invert(A,B) :- invert(B,A), !.` work?

Comment: @Enigmativity `ERROR: Out of local stack`

Comment: @lurker Then why does it not show up at the end of every query's results list?

Comment: Because not every query leaves a "choice point".

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to achieve with `invert/2`. From your comments, it sounds like, semantically, `Left` is an *inverse* of `Right`, and `Right` is an *inverse* of `Left`. I think the key is in how you define that relationship in detail. You haven't shown what `invert/2` really does, so it's hard to offer specific advice in that regard. But it looks like you're trying to force your real `invert/2` to do something "after the fact", but `invert/2` may need refactoring.

Comment: @lurker It determines whether `Left` and `Right` are opposites, in the system I have. It doesn't have an algorithm (for most cases), it's just declared by facts.

Comment: Give a concrete ground (variable free) example where `invert/2` should be true.

Comment: @false `invert(implicit, explicit). invert(explicit, X), X = implicit.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I'd consider. First, make sure that the predicate you create for establishing the symmetry of the relationship in your facts has a different name than your facts. Having the name be the same usually leads to issues such as infinite recursion. Secondly, if the facts are under your control to declare, be consistent about whether the facts explicitly declare the symmetrical case or not. If they do, then you don't need the extra predicate. If they don't, then you need an extra predicate.

For example, with symmetries explicitly declared:

```
opposite(a, b).
opposite(b, a).
opposite(c, d).
opposite(d, c).
```

You don't need an extra predicate to get the symmetrical solutions for `opposite`.

An example where the symmetries are not explicitly declared:

```
opposite(a, b).
opposite(c, d).

inverted(X, Y) :- opposite(X, Y).
inverted(X, Y) :- opposite(Y, X).
```

In this case, querying `inverted/2` instead of `opposite/2` will handle the symmetry in the relationships.

Comment: Now all attempts to find an inversion give the correct answer, but if I press `;` they loop infinitely.

Comment: @Viko: lurker's definition always terminates.

Comment: @Viko I believe I did properly answer the question as it was posed and given the limited context. Your indefinite loop is due to something you're not showing.  I would suggest posting a new question with your new code to show what's going on. It would be improper to now change your code in this question since it would change the context of the answer.